# Is it possible to project a video frame into another image?

Tags: c++, opencv

I capture frames from a video (1.) and want to project this rectangular area as a subimage into a detected area in the target image (2.) .

[image]
The area in the target image (2.) is not orthogonal I already have the coordinates to draw lines around the target area (determined by homography).

Is there any method which provides functionality to copy the source frame (3.) (e.g. using bilinear interpolation) into the target image in a distinct area (4.) ?

I also need to translate the smaler (video frame) image.

Comment: You can restrict operations on a rectangular sub-area of the destination image by `cvSetImageROI()` (Rectangle of Interest). Once that done, just `cvResize()` your video frame into the destination.

Comment: @FrankH Thanks, a quick google showed this http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Region_of_Interest_(ROI) in my case I have already rotated the video frame and want to fit in the scene with out overwriting the difference of the rotated video and its bounding box in my target image.

Comment: Or are you saying "not orthogonal" you mean the destination is a rotated rectangle ? In that case, I'd use an intermediate target image the size of the non-rotated bounding box of the final destination "quad", then do `getAffineTransform()` followed by `warpAffine()` and finally blend the result of that into the destination which again is restricted to the _bounding box_ of the rotated quad. That final blend step so that pixels outside the quad aren't touched.

Comment: Blending is done via `addWeighted()`. You'll have to have rotated quad in the destination all zeroed out and the area outside the rotated video frame all zeoed out as well, in that case image addition with weights of `1` on both will give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, looking through the reference, `cvCopy()` with a mask image might be more precise than `cvAddWeighted()` because the affine transformation might have inaccuracies along the edges.

Comment: @FrankH thank you for the pointers. I will try this over the weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drawing clarifies the exact needs. Something like this should do:

```
void warpVideoToQuad(
    IplImage *videoFrame,
    IplImage *target,
    CvSeq *tgt_quad)
{
    int width = videoFrame->width, height = videoFrame->height;

    CvPoint2D32f src_rect[] =
        { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, height }, { width, height }, { width, 0.0 } };
    CvPoint2D32f dst_quad[4];

    // a little kludgy as cvGetPerspectiveTransform() and cvBoundingRect()
    // use different arg types - the former a point array the latter a seq
    cvCvtSeqToArray(tgt_quad, dst_quad);

    CvMat *warper = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1);
    CvRect tgt_rect = cvBoundingRect(tgt_quad);

    IplImage *warpTgt = cvCreateImage(CvSize(tgt_rect.width, tgt_rect.height),
        videoFrame->depth, videoFrame->nChannels);
    cvZero(warpTgt);

    cvGetPerspectiveTransform(src_rect, dst_quad, &warper);
    cvGetQuadrangleSubPix(videoFrame, warpTgt, warper);

    cvSetImageROI(target, tgt_rect);
    cvCopy(warpTgt, target, warpTgt);
    cvResetImageROI(target);

    delete warpTgt;
    delete warper;
}
```

I can't test this right now, so just for illustration. Will edit as appropriate later.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `warpPerspective()` to achieve this. First get the appropriate perspective transformation with `getPerspectiveTransform()`(the quad you drew in the question is not a parallelogram, so an affine transformation will not do). The function will take as input arguments the pixel coordinates of the video frame's corners ([0;0][0;frame.cols] etc.) and the pixel coordinates of the corners of the lines you drew in the target area.
Now that you have the transformation, use it with `warpPerspective()` to warp the video frame to a blank image the size of your target image. Use a copy operation with a ROI mask (such as those described by FrankH) to insert the warped area into the actual target image.